# BTRFS Raid1 balance having opposite of expected behavior

Tags: btrfs

I have 4 drives in raid1. I recently replaced a failing drive with a new larger drive. The new 12TB drive seems under-utilized. I ran a balance expecting data to be relocated from the 3 other drives to the new one. However, it appears data was being moved the wrong way. Can someone explain this odd behavior?

```
# btrfs fi usage /av
Overall:
    Device size:              29.11TiB
    Device allocated:         11.32TiB
    Device unallocated:       17.79TiB
    Device missing:              0.00B
    Used:                     10.90TiB
    Free (estimated):          9.10TiB  (min: 9.10TiB)
    Data ratio:                   2.00
    Metadata ratio:               2.00
    Global reserve:          512.00MiB  (used: 0.00B)

Data,RAID1: Size:5.65TiB, Used:5.44TiB (96.32%)
   /dev/sdh    5.13TiB
   /dev/sdf    3.33TiB
   /dev/sdg    2.54TiB
   /dev/sde  310.00GiB

Metadata,RAID1: Size:9.00GiB, Used:7.28GiB (80.91%)
   /dev/sdh    6.00GiB
   /dev/sdf    3.00GiB
   /dev/sdg    6.00GiB
   /dev/sde    3.00GiB

System,RAID1: Size:32.00MiB, Used:976.00KiB (2.98%)
   /dev/sdg   32.00MiB
   /dev/sde   32.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sdh    2.14TiB
   /dev/sdf    2.13TiB
   /dev/sdg    2.91TiB
   /dev/sde   10.61TiB
```

During an unfiltered balance, I started monitoring the progress as such:

```
# btrfs fi show /av
Label: 'av'  uuid: a0e1cb85-1b4f-4657-971d-ba1d8c1bb772
    Total devices 4 FS bytes used 5.45TiB
    devid    4 size 7.28TiB used 5.13TiB path /dev/sdh
    devid    5 size 5.46TiB used 3.33TiB path /dev/sdf
    devid    6 size 5.46TiB used 2.57TiB path /dev/sdg
    devid    7 size 10.91TiB used 330.06GiB path /dev/sde

# btrfs fi show 
Label: 'av'  uuid: a0e1cb85-1b4f-4657-971d-ba1d8c1bb772
    Total devices 4 FS bytes used 5.45TiB
    devid    4 size 7.28TiB used 5.13TiB path /dev/sdh
    devid    5 size 5.46TiB used 3.33TiB path /dev/sdf
    devid    6 size 5.46TiB used 2.56TiB path /dev/sdg
    devid    7 size 10.91TiB used 320.03GiB path /dev/sde

# btrfs fi show
Label: 'av'  uuid: a0e1cb85-1b4f-4657-971d-ba1d8c1bb772
    Total devices 4 FS bytes used 5.45TiB
    devid    4 size 7.28TiB used 5.13TiB path /dev/sdh
    devid    5 size 5.46TiB used 3.33TiB path /dev/sdf
    devid    6 size 5.46TiB used 2.55TiB path /dev/sdg
    devid    7 size 10.91TiB used 313.03GiB path /dev/sde
```

The 12TB, drive 7, is not having new data added, it's being removed.
What's up with that? And, how do I get data to spread more evenly across all drives?

**Additional Information**

```
btrfs --version
btrfs-progs v5.4.1
```

I don't remember which version of btrfs I used to create the volume or add the device.

Comment: What command(s) did you use to replace the drive? `btrfs-replace` should be all that's needed.

Comment: @Emmanuel Rosa It was many months ago, but fortunately I keep a long history. Looks like I did this: `btrfs device delete missing /av` and then `btrfs device add /dev/sde /av`